# Importing a database from the Django settings.py?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, heroku

I'm writing a Django app that uses MongoDB as it's primary database. I simply need the app to make a query against the database (hosted on Heroku) and display results for each user request.

I'm aware Python modules such as PyMongo exist for easily connecting/interacting with MongoDB, but I don't want to have to establish a database connection each time a user requests the page. I want the database base to connect upon launching the Django app.

Right now in my `settings.py` file I have:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'heroku_app33177236',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        # 'USER': 'admin',
        # 'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'mongodb://admin:#####@ds041581.mongolab.com:41581/heroku_app33177236',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        #'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

And in my `views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # !!!!!! I want to do something like this:
    rooms = db.studybug.find()

    return render_to_response('studybug/index.html', rooms, context)
```

As you can see above, I simply want to query the database each time a user requests and display the result.

I don't really see the point or need of defining models for this, because the operation is so lightweight.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
from settings import db
```

??

Thanks!

Comment: Django only supports SQL in this way. You would need to create a connection to Mongo with Pymongo. Django still connects each time but utilizes a connectionpool. Checkout https://github.com/django-nonrel for a custom django.

Comment: @Joe Doherty So there's no way to establish a Mongo connection upon startup and sustain that connection throughout the app's lifespan?

Comment: That is not how DB connections work when on the web. It all depends on the way you deploy your app. An instance of your app may not last very long so would need to connect. If you are using gunicorn the workers don't live forever.